# Shouldn't dismiss (nsviewcontroller method to dismiss view controller) be a class method?

Tags: swift, macos, dismiss, nsviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

Apple documentation says, dismiss(viewcontroller) dismisses the viewcontroller passed in the argument. currently i can call this method only on an NSViewController instance. shouldn't this method be a class method so that we don't have to call dismiss(_) after creating an instance or using the same instance...

shouldn't dismiss(_) be called by

NSViewController.dismiss(vc) instead of NSViewController.init().dismiss(vc) or vc.dismiss(vc)??

or is there a specific reason why it is an instance method

Comment: That is because you have to tell MacOS which VC are you trying to dismiss. It needs to know which one is supposed to be dismissed, it can't just make a guess for you. To remedy that, you can always write your own extension of NSViewController to dismiss the top ViewController in your Application. Alternatively, you can write a BaseViewController, have your ViewControllers inherit from it and write the generic Dismiss method in that baseviewController and then call it like "self.dismiss()" from your Child ViewControllers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @NSNoob "It needs to know which one is supposed to be dismissed, it can't just make a guess for you. " yea its correct and that is passed as an argument. if i want to dismiss a view controller vc, i can pass it and its not necessary to call dismiss using vc.
Eg: NSViewController.init().dismiss(vc) and vc.dismiss(vc), both would work.
My question was why was it designed like that and not any alternative.

Comment: @Willeke I am sorry, I couldn't find the answer in this link as of why its an instance method and not a class method.